# Reading .osm.pbf or converting .osm.pbf to .osm

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

I want to extract some information from a `.osm.pbf` file. I looked through `OpenStreetMapX.jl` package but didn't find a function to read this data. I am wondering if anyone know a method to read this data. Alternatively is there a way to convert `.osm.pbf` to `.osm` file so that I found just use the `get_map_data()` method offered by `OpenStreetMapX` package

Comment: You can try https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert, i.e. `osmconvert myfile.osm.pbf > myfile.osm`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) for that:

```
osmosis --read-pbf myFile.osm.pbf --write-xml myFile.osm
```

Comment: Additional tip - when working with larger maps always run it through OSM filter (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) before processing with OpenStreetMapX

Comment: The wiki says osmosis won't continue development, one should look into new tools especially when first learning them.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) to do this:

```
osmium cat myFile.osm.pbf -o myFile.osm
```