# Error when using OSMOSIS to extract data from OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I am trying to replicate the example [in this page](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osmosis/). I downloaded the data and run this code (the example data of that page can be downloaded [from here](https://learnosm.org/files/sample_osmosis.osm.pbf)):

`osmosis --rbf sample_osmosis.osm.pbf --nkv keyValueList="amenity.school" --wx schools.osm`

I am using Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon and installed osmosis by using Sypantic (version 0.47).

I downloaded the example in the previous page and run the previous code in the folder containing the `.pbf` file.

However, I am getting this error:

```
osmosis --rbf sample_osmosis.osm.pbf --nkv keyValueList="amenity.school" --wx schools.osm
nov. 18, 2021 11:55:56 P. M. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFORMACIÓN: Osmosis Version 0.47
nov. 18, 2021 11:55:56 P. M. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFORMACIÓN: Preparing pipeline.
nov. 18, 2021 11:55:56 P. M. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFORMACIÓN: Launching pipeline execution.
nov. 18, 2021 11:55:56 P. M. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFORMACIÓN: Pipeline executing, waiting for completion.
nov. 18, 2021 11:55:56 P. M. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskManager waitForCompletion
GRAVE: Thread for task 1-rbf failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pbf2.v0_6.PbfReader.run(PbfReader.java:87)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 2 more

nov. 18, 2021 11:55:56 P. M. org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
GRAVE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed.
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForCompletion(Pipeline.java:146)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran with success your exact command with the Osmosis Version 0.48.3 using your example data (`osmosis --rbf sample_osmosis.osm.pbf --nkv keyValueList="amenity.school" --wx school.osm`): `INFOS: Total execution time: 439 milliseconds`.

My Osmosis version is possibly different from yours, but the sample_osmosis.osm.pbf file possibly evolved too.

FYI I encountered on 2022-07-20 the same error message (`"GRAVE: Thread for task 1-rbf failed"`) using the latest GeoFabrik OSM data from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/monaco-220719.osm.pbf with a basic Osmosis command: `osmosis --read-pbf file=monaco-latest.osm.pbf --write-xml file=monaco-latest.osm`. After analysis and exchange with the GeoFabrik support, it was related to a bug that has been fixed the day after.

Waiting for a format fix, a good workaround has been to "clean" the pbf with osmconvert: `osmconvert" monaco-latest.osm.pbf>monaco-new.osm.pbf --out-pbf`

Answer (score 0):

### Tutorials

- [**Reading .osm.pbf or converting .osm.pbf to .osm**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74688730/10190171)

### Description

- [**Osmium Tool**](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/)

After encountering this problem I used `osmium` to extract `.pbf` to `.osm`

```
osmium cat xxx.pbf -o xxx.osm
```